# Bootstrap-select plugin - programmatically trigger click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-select

How can I trigger on click event programmatically the second option (select TV)?
I use bootstrap-select plugin.
I want to mimic the same behavior as the user clicks on the "TV" option.

my code in this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/xzv9qkwe/

(btw, I tried to write a snippet here but it throws me an exception error when I include CDN of bootstrap-select... but it works fine in jsfiddle link. If you can tell me the reason for it, I will also edit the snippet here).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary">
  <option>Computer</option>
  <option>TV</option>
</select>
```

Bootstrap-select plugin link:
https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to run a function every time the user selects a new input in the dropdown. Am I correct?

Comment: Please elaborate more on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listening for a click, listen for a change.

If you want to use the click event, you will need to use something other than a select element.

```js
const output = document.querySelector("#output");
var changeCntr = 0;

document.querySelector(".selectpicker")
  .addEventListener("change", e => {
    if (e.target.value == "TV") {
      changeCntr++;
      output.innerText = `Changed to TV ${changeCntr} times`;
    }
  });
```

```css
select {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  min-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary">
  <option>Computer</option>
  <option>TV</option>
</select>

<div id="output">

</div>
```